# Is it possible implement fragment to ListView item?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Is it possible implement fragment to `ListView` item?

Finally, I would like to achieve this effect. Maybe there are other solutions I do not know about?

[image]

**[Edit] More information:**
 To be honest, I experiment a little bit. In that case, I wanna just make something like card with two sides. When you click current just hide one and show second.

Comment: if you want fragment inside listview for no need to write code for each fragment ?

Comment: if it is your thinking then make customView and add it in listview insted of fragment

Comment: Why on a earth you do want to add fragment inside listview ?

Comment: To be honest, I experiment a little bit. In that case, I wanna just make something like card with two sides. When you click current just hide one and show second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, this is a very bad aproach. Each fragment has its own lifecycle and given that ListView behaviour, you will have to manage the fragment's reuse (view holder pattern). The result risk to be very painful to maintain.

In this case, you should consider to use a [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) as replacement to fragments.

Comment: So better solution is just to create my own Views and manages them like changing data, hide or show? To be honest, I experiment a little bit. In that case, I wanna just make something like card with two sides. When you click current just hide one and show second.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, the idea of a customView is to generalize. Think about how this view will react in a normal state (wherever in your app). Then your `ListView`'s item can set how they will act for each row. Edit your post to add this intentions and more precisions to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need `GridView` not `ListView` here
Yes, can do that. But it is not at all good because`fragments` are used to use the full screen with out wasting it when the screen is came to picture. What is the requirement to you. Why you wanted to implement `fragment` inside `ListView`

Here is the documentation for fragments read it. For what it is going to use

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

It is only for better experience to user in terms of `tabs and mobile phones`